# Arduino AES ESP8266

Tags: node.js, aes, esp8266

i am using a library to code a message to AES CBC
library : https://github.com/suculent/thinx-aes-lib
version 2.2.0
from nodeJS i have :

```
CLEAR DATA: TEST
IV: 3b698860538401cdd146504278aeecc9
KEY: df4f66809bafe58fe16aba7f4cb3e8bc
ENCRYPTED DATA : 560d5ecae14404f4d143931d6d4e4705
```

i want to encode the message but i cant , the cipher i am getting is diffrent than the cipher i got from NodeJS

tried many ways but all faild

```
#include "AESLib.h"
// TEST MUST BE OUTPUT

//byte KEY[]         = {0xdf , 0x4f , 0x66 , 0x80 , 0x9b , 0xaf , 0xe5 , 0x8f , 0xe1 , 0x6a , 0xba , 0x7f , 0x4c , 0xb3 , 0xe8 , 0xbc};
//byte IV[N_BLOCK]  = {0x3b , 0x69 , 0x88 , 0x60 , 0x53 , 0x84 , 0x01 , 0xcd , 0xd1 , 0x46 , 0x50 , 0x42 , 0x78 , 0xae , 0xec , 0xc9};
//byte DATA[]       ={0x56 , 0x0d , 0x5e , 0xca , 0xe1 , 0x44 , 0x04 , 0xf4 , 0xd1 , 0x43 , 0x93 , 0x1d , 0x6d , 0x4e , 0x47 , 0x05 };

    #define BAUD 115200
    
    AESLib aesLib;

#define INPUT_BUFFER_LIMIT (128 + 1) // designed for Arduino UNO, not stress-tested anymore (this works with readBuffer[129])

unsigned char cleartext[INPUT_BUFFER_LIMIT] = {0}; // THIS IS INPUT BUFFER (FOR TEXT)
unsigned char ciphertext[2*INPUT_BUFFER_LIMIT] = {0}; // THIS IS OUTPUT BUFFER (FOR BASE64-ENCODED ENCRYPTED DATA)

unsigned char readBuffer[] = "TEST";

// AES Encryption Key (same as in node-js example)
byte aes_key[]       = {0xdf , 0x4f , 0x66 , 0x80 , 0x9b , 0xaf , 0xe5 , 0x8f , 0xe1 , 0x6a , 0xba , 0x7f , 0x4c , 0xb3 , 0xe8 , 0xbc};

// General initialization vector (same as in node-js example) (you must use your own IV's in production for full security!!!)
byte aes_iv[N_BLOCK] = {0x3b , 0x69 , 0x88 , 0x60 , 0x53 , 0x84 , 0x01 , 0xcd , 0xd1 , 0x46 , 0x50 , 0x42 , 0x78 , 0xae , 0xec , 0xc9};

// Generate IV (once)
void aes_init() {
  aesLib.set_paddingmode(paddingMode::CMS);
}

uint16_t encrypt_to_ciphertext(char * msg, uint16_t msgLen, byte iv[]) {
  Serial.println("Calling encrypt (string)...");
  // aesLib.get_cipher64_length(msgLen);
  int cipherlength = aesLib.encrypt((byte*)msg, msgLen, (char*)ciphertext, aes_key, sizeof(aes_key), iv);
  
        //// HERE IS WHERE I READ THE CIPHER            
    Serial.println();
    for(int i=0;i < cipherlength ;i++)
    {
      Serial.printf("%02X",ciphertext[i]);
    }
    Serial.println();
    
  return cipherlength;
}

uint16_t decrypt_to_cleartext(byte msg[], uint16_t msgLen, byte iv[]) {
  Serial.print("Calling decrypt...; ");
  uint16_t dec_bytes = aesLib.decrypt(msg, msgLen, (char*)cleartext, aes_key, sizeof(aes_key), iv);
  Serial.print("Decrypted bytes: "); Serial.println(dec_bytes);
  return dec_bytes;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(BAUD);
  Serial.setTimeout(60000);
  delay(2000);

  aes_init(); 

}

/* non-blocking wait function */
void wait(unsigned long milliseconds) {
  unsigned long timeout = millis() + milliseconds;
  while (millis() < timeout) {
    yield();
  }
}

unsigned long loopcount = 0;


byte enc_iv[N_BLOCK] =      {0x3b , 0x69 , 0x88 , 0x60 , 0x53 , 0x84 , 0x01 , 0xcd , 0xd1 , 0x46 , 0x50 , 0x42 , 0x78 , 0xae , 0xec , 0xc9};
byte enc_iv_to[N_BLOCK]   = {0x3b , 0x69 , 0x88 , 0x60 , 0x53 , 0x84 , 0x01 , 0xcd , 0xd1 , 0x46 , 0x50 , 0x42 , 0x78 , 0xae , 0xec , 0xc9};
byte enc_iv_from[N_BLOCK] = {0x3b , 0x69 , 0x88 , 0x60 , 0x53 , 0x84 , 0x01 , 0xcd , 0xd1 , 0x46 , 0x50 , 0x42 , 0x78 , 0xae , 0xec , 0xc9};

void loop() {

  Serial.print("readBuffer length: "); Serial.println(sizeof(readBuffer));

   // must not exceed INPUT_BUFFER_LIMIT bytes; may contain a newline
  sprintf((char*)cleartext, "%s", readBuffer);

  // Encrypt
  // iv_block gets written to, provide own fresh copy... so each iteration of encryption will be the same.
  uint16_t msgLen = sizeof(readBuffer);
  memcpy(enc_iv, enc_iv_to, sizeof(enc_iv_to));
  uint16_t encLen = encrypt_to_ciphertext((char*)cleartext, msgLen, enc_iv);
  Serial.print("Encrypted length = "); Serial.println(encLen );

//  Serial.println("Encrypted. Decrypting..."); Serial.println(encLen ); Serial.flush();
//  memcpy(enc_iv, enc_iv_from, sizeof(enc_iv_from));
//  uint16_t decLen = decrypt_to_cleartext(ciphertext, encLen , enc_iv);
//  Serial.print("Decrypted cleartext of length: "); Serial.println(decLen);
//  Serial.print("Decrypted cleartext:\n"); Serial.println((char*)cleartext);
//
//  if (strcmp((char*)readBuffer, (char*)cleartext) == 0) {
//    Serial.println("Decrypted correctly.");
//  } else {
//    Serial.println("Decryption test failed.");
//  }

  Serial.println("---");
  delay(5000);
}
```

dose any one know why i am getting the wrong output ?  my output is :
7673424862437068714A722B30466C625146346B47773D3D
which should be
560d5ecae14404f4d143931d6d4e4705

Comment: `AESLib::encrypt()` Base64 encodes the ciphertext, i.e. the hex encoded value `76734248...` corresponds to the Base64 encoded value `vsBHbCphqJr+0FlbQF4kGw==`. If this is Base64 decoded and then hex encoded the result is `bec0476c2a61a89afed0595b405e241b`. This value can be compared with your reference value. Decrypting `bec047...` with your key and IV (AES,CBC, PKCS7 padding), results hex encoded in `5445535400`. The first 4 bytes are ASCII decoded `TEST`. Apparently your code encrypts somewhere a terminating `0`.

Comment: @Topaco thanks , so this is not a problem with my code but the library ? i got a little confused , i am new to this ,or should i just take the out put of encrypt and decode it with base64 ? can u tell what dose this mean ? This value can be compared with your reference value. Decrypting

Comment: No, I suspect it is a problem with your code. Instead of TEST you encrypt TEST\0, where 0 is probably a terminating 0.

Comment: @Topaco when i change "TEST" to "TEST\0" i get this :
454F7A5250554B6B684E5356374B46784231396575513D3D

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with hex and base64 encoding. Then you should debug your code and check if your parameters have the values they should have. This way you will find the bug.